# Native error in .NET Core Blazor WebAssembly

Tags: .net-core, blazor, webassembly, blazor-client-side

My task is to run a CLI command (in the client's system) and to show the output to the user on the Web app. [assume, **a web-based cmd.exe**]

Based on reading about WebAssembly's capabilities, I used the .NET CORE Blazor WebAssembly to do the task. But using the **System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo** in Client throws runtime error **Native error= Cannot find the specified file**.

Please let me know if my understanding of WebAssembly is wrong. Also, suggest how I could accomplish the task?

**Code used in Razor page:**

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    quiz = await Http.GetJsonAsync<List<QuizItem>>("Quiz");

    // My actual code...
    string process = @"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe", arguments = "start", workingFolder = ".";
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startinfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo {
        FileName = process, Arguments = arguments, WorkingDirectory = workingFolder,
        CreateNoWindow = false, UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardError = true, RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    };
    System.Diagnostics.Process proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start (startinfo);
    if (proc == null) throw new Exception ($"Unable to execute '{process}'");
}
```

**Console log for reference:**

[image]

Comment: Imagine what a security threat this would be. Open a website and suddenly someone accesses your filesystem without any interaction of you.

Comment: So, Can I take it as the task is impossible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The permissions of blazor are limited by the browser javascript sandbox, so you cannot do anything you also cannot do in javascript. Starting processes is one of them.

Answer (score 1):

First off, A Blazor WebAssembly App is not a .NET CORE app.

You can't execute CLI commands in a Blazor WebAssembly App which is more or less identical to JavaScript in scope and limitations. A Blazor WebAssembly App is single-threaded and runs in the same sandbox of JavaScript. In JavaScript you can't access the user's file system, which implies that you won't be able to do it using a WebAssembly App.

I'm not sure I get you. If you want to display data retrieved from the server, why can't you display it in Html elements such as input box list box, etc. ?